# CURL выводит ответ но не возвращает его в переменную

Tags: php, curl

Ниже код:

```
$url = "http://site.ru/my_exchange_2.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth";  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Код выполняется, выдает ответ:

```
success PHPSESSID aooom9tmurdnrdukfgkk631421 sessid=e519c36f6765ec9f8eaf30ecd10d9f4d
```

Но в переменной `$result` нет ответа, а только `bool(true)` если смотреть через `var_dump`.

Как получить в переменную то, что выводит curl на экран? Меня интересует `sessid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте эту опцию:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`